# Retry failed service call but use different implementation

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, retry-logic

The code I'm working with has the following structure.

```
public interface SomeService {
    Optional<SomeClass> getThing();
    // more methods
}

public abstract class SomeServiceBase implements SomeService {
    Optional<SomeClass> getThing() {
       // logic
       this.onGetThing();
    }

    protected abstract Optional<SomeClass> onGetThing();
}
```

Additionally, there are then 3 different classes that extends `SomeServiceBase` and each one calls to a different 3rd party exteranl API to get some results and they all implement thier own version of `onGetThing()`.

```
class FooService extends SomeServiceBase { @Override protected Optional<SomeClass> onGetThing() { } }
class DooService extends SomeServiceBase { @Override protected Optional<SomeClass> onGetThing() { } }
class RooService extends SomeServiceBase { @Override protected Optional<SomeClass> onGetThing() { } }
```

There's a factory service that wires up all three of the above services and returns the right one based on a "Provider" that is passed in from the client to the API.

`Optional<SomeClass> myThing = SomeServiceFactory.getService(provider).getThing();`

What I need to do is if `FooService` doesn't return a result, I want to retry with `DooService`. But I am struggling trying to find a good way to implement this in a somewhat generic reusable way. Any help is appreciated. Let me know if I need to provide more details.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you could take a look a to the Circuit breaker pattern.
It allows you to use a "fallback" if the original call raised an exception.
If i may resume with your sample :

- A circuit breaker is provided/developped around the `FooService`
- If everything is fine on the `FooService`, the original response will be given back
- Else if the `FooService` does not provide a response  or throw an exception, you will go to the linked fallback
- In your fallback you will implement the call to the `DooService`

You can give a try with [Resilience4J](https://resilience4j.readme.io/docs/circuitbreaker) (you have some samples with diffrent kind of implementation)   or [Netflix Circuit Breaker](https://github.com/Netflix/Hystrix/wiki/How-it-Works#CircuitBreaker) (but deprecated)

Comment: Thanks, not a bad idea. I'll take a look and see what's what.